# Python Feedparser Not Showing Entries

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I've watched a lot of videos about `feedparser` library in tutorials everybody use this library like in my code but my code is not working... Anyone help me? [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sf8k.png)

I still can't get output even though I tried different variances.

My code:

```
import feedparser

url = "cnnturk.com/feed/rss/all/news"

rss_source = feedparser.parse(url)

for news in rss_source.entries:
    print(news.title)
```

Comment: Please post the script as text not screenshot.

Comment: Please not in comment. You can delete now.